# AngularJS 'fn' is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Here is my front-end code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn text-center" ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div ng-repeat="project in _projects">
            <div class="project-container col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered text-center">
                <div class="project-thumb-container">
                    <div  class="project-thumb" style="background-image: url('img/project{{project.projectid}}.jpg');">
                        <div class="inner-arrow" ui-sref="portal.dashboard({ projectid: {{project.projectid}} })">
                            <span class="icon-arrow-right fa-5x"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-settings like-link">
                            <span class="fa fa-gear fa-2x" ng-click="open('test')"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-share like-link">
                            <span class="fa fa-users fa-2x" ng-click="open('test')"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project-container col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered text-center">
            <div class="project-thumb-container">
                <div class="project-thumb thumb-new">
                    <div class="plus-icon-container">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus fa-5x"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4><i>Add Project</i></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And here is my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('controllers', ['Projects']).controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, Projects) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.error = null;

    _self.processing = true;
    Projects.getProjectList().then(function(data){
        $scope._projects = data;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        _self.error = true;
        _self.processing = false;
    });
});
```

Here is my route:

```
.state('root.projects', {
    url: "/projects",
    controller: "ProjectCtrl as ProjectCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
})
```

When that code is ran on the front-end, I keep getting this error: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProjectCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: is `.module("controllers", ` your app module? Do you have `ng-app="controllers"`?

Comment: In addition to above comment, make sure that you've included all your scripts. This is a very common error when Angular is looking for a module/controller/function/whathaveyou and the file is not included or defined via, as above, `ng-app`.

Comment: Where would the ng-app go?

Comment: I have an `ng-app` on the main HTML file

Comment: @dennismonsewicz, yes, it is included on the root element of your app, typically, `<html>` or `<body>`, etc... And it should specify the app's module, e.g. `"ng-app="controllers"`